# Makefile: Split binary, source and header files into directories

Tags: makefile

This is my first attempt to create a make-file for compiling. I'm working on a project where I want to divide files under compiling, sow i have 3 folders: src, bin and header. Today I compile with the command gcc file1.c file2.c file3.c -lncurses

How can I write a makefile to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
bin/myBinaryName: file1.c file2.c file3.c
    gcc $^ -Iheader -lncurses -o $@

vpath %.c src
```

There are more sophisticated approaches than this, but I suspect that you are taking the same course as the other newcomers who have asked very similar questions over the past couple of weeks.

If you want a more basic introduction, or a more sophisticated makefile, you can try a different question.

**EDIT:**

Let's try something simpler. Write this makefile (and name it `makefile`):

```
all:
    echo hello world
```

Note that the whitespace before "echo" is a TAB. Now try `make` on the command line. What happens?

Comment: bin/myBinaryName is a folder ? Should this makefile been placed in the  root folder for src and bin, or in the src folder ?

Comment: @user265767, you didn't specify, so I supposed that you wanted the binary to go in `bin/` and I named it `myBinaryName`. This makefile belongs in the parent directory (i.e. root folder).

Comment: Sure that bin/myBinaryName: file1.c file2.c file3.c should look like this, and not like this: bin/myBinaryName: file1.c file2.c file3.c, where : is removed ? After removing : make stops complaining about that bin/myBinaryName: No such file or directory. Now make complains about Permission denied, every file and folder have Read/Write for all users ?